# Отправка почты

Tags: email, php

Подскажите, можно ли отправлять письма с локального сервера на реальные почтовые адреса?

Comment: @Женька Сидоров, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Какой сервер используется?

Answer (score 3):

Да, [`bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php).

Comment: А где там описано? Я просто тоже искал, не мог найти.

Comment: @Sergalas, открой ссылку-то, там даже по-русски все расписано.

Comment: Пока только письма на локалку приходят,мож че неправильно делаю

Comment: Для этого нужно настраивать правильно сервер. А это уже не входит в ответ вашего вопроса.

Comment: @Женька Сидоров, сервер-реципиент может отвергать все письма, которые не соответствуют его внутренним требованиям. Обычно среди прочего требуется совпадение ptr-записи, которую на локалке не организовать никак. Используйте SwiftMailer, у него есть sandbox-режим, в котором ничего не отправляется, но саму работу проверить можно.